# c # does not show me the whole result

Tags: c#

Good Morning,

I have the following problem, I am a student and I need to solve an exercise in Visual Studio 2012.

I need to write an algorithm that requests the amount of coins of $ 50, $ 100, $ 200 and $ 500, 1000 and $ 1000, $ 2000, $ 5000, $ 10000, $ 20000 and $ 50000 and shows the total money collected on the day.

I have to do this in Windows Forms.
I have attempted to do this but my result only shows the first 3 digits in the result. I thought this was wrong, but then I did it in a calculator and the result is actually correct if I only take into account the first 3 digits. However, I want it to show all the digits of the operation.

Below is what I've attempted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtBil50_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txbCalcu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double mon1 = double.Parse(txtMo50.Text);
            double mon2 = double.Parse(txtMo100.Text);
            double mon3 = double.Parse(txtMo200.Text);
            double mon4 = double.Parse(txtMo500.Text);
            double mon5 = double.Parse(txtMo1000.Text);
            double bil1 = double.Parse(txtBil1000.Text);
            double bil2 = double.Parse(txtBil2000.Text);
            double bil3 = double.Parse(txtBil5000.Text);
            double bil4 = double.Parse(txtBil1000.Text);
            double bil5 = double.Parse(txtBil20.Text);
            double bil6 = double.Parse(txtBil50.Text);

            double multi1 = mon1 * 50;
            double multi2 = mon2 * 100;
            double multi3 = mon3 * 200;
            double multi4 = mon4 * 500;
            double multi5 = mon5 * 1000;
            double bill1 = bil1 * 1000;
            double bill2 = bil2 * 2000;
            double bill3 = bil3 * 5000;
            double bill4 = bil4 * 10000;
            double bill5 = bil5 * 20000;
            double bill6 = bil6 * 50000;

            double suma= mon1 + mon2 + mon3 + mon4 + mon5 + bil1 + bil2 + bil3 + bil4 + bil5 + bil6;
            txtCal.Text = ""+suma ;

        }
    }
}
```

I hope for your help thanks

Comment: whats your expected vs actual result?

Comment: also, can you adjust your question slightly to change the textbox.text values to what youre entering or put comments at the side so that we can try and replicate your issue better

Comment: Why don't you actually ***use***  `multi1` through `multi5` and `bill1` through `bill6`?

Comment: @Rafalon that would most probably solve the OP issue

Comment: I think you made an mistake in the line double bil4 = ... count your zeroes

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem comes from the fact that you sum:

```
mon1 + mon2 + mon3 + mon4 + mon5 + bil1 + bil2 + bil3 + bil4 + bil5 + bil6
```

where you actually want to sum:

```
multi1 + multi2 + multi3 + multi4 + multi5 + bill1 + bill2 + bill3 + bill4 + bill5 + bill6
```

Also, as pointed out by nabuchodonossor, this line:

```
double bil4 = double.Parse(txtBil1000.Text);
```

should more likely be:

```
double bil4 = double.Parse(txtBil10000.Text);
// -------------------------------^^^^
```

Again, `bil5` and `bil6` take respectively for input `txtBil20` and `txtBil50` where one would expect `txtBil20000` and `txtBil50000`.

---

As pointed out by @V0ldek, a cleaner way of storing those values could be for example:

```
var coinCount = new Dictionary<int, double>();
coinCount[50] = double.Parse(txtMo50.Text);
coinCount[100] = double.Parse(txtMo100.Text);
// ...

var billCount = new Dictionary<int, double>();
billCount[1000] = double.Parse(txtBil1000.Text);
// ...

var coinAmount = new Dictionary<int, double>();
coinAmount[50] = 50*coinCount[50];
// ...

var billAmount = new Dictionary<int, double>();
billAmount[1000] = 1000*billCount[1000];
// ...
```

Of course, here you could even store the different coins and bills values so you do not use magic numbers like above.

[Here](http://tpcg.io/tm35WA) is a runnable piece of code illustrating the above.

Comment: I think it's crucial to mention that naming your variables like `bil1` and `bill1` is a terrible idea, and leads to errors like these. They should be changed to anything more descriptive. Can you tell the difference between `bil1` and `bill1` by simply looking at the names? No? Then you're naming them wrong. Not to mention the unfortunate `ll1` combo of ambiguity.

Comment: I edited my answer to include that, thanks for the comment